# Kafka-python KafkaProducer __init__ takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python

I am encountering the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
connection = KafkaProducer(kafka_settings['topic'], bootstrap_servers=kafka_settings['bootstrap_servers'])
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This is strange to me because I followed the documentation given. https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html

How do I resolve this?

Comment: I'm looking at the docs now, and the topic name parameter doesn't exist when you initialize a producer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html suggest that `bootstrap_servers` is parameter given during creating `KafkaProducer`, but topic should be specified when using `.send` method, please try following

```
connection = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_settings['bootstrap_servers'])
future = connection.send(kafka_settings['topic'], b'your_message_here')
```